# Error compiling pipeline when using Scio typed bigquery api with apache-beam

Tags: scala, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I'm trying to use typed `bigquery` api as shown in `scio` [website](https://spotify.github.io/scio/io/Type-Safe-BigQuery.html#bigquerytype-fromtable):

```
@BigQueryType.fromTable("sandbox-data:Users.uid")
class UIDTable
```

I run `sbt pack -Dbigquery.project=sandbox-data` in the command line and get the following error:

```
exception during macro expansion:
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Property bigquery.project not set. Use - 
Dbigquery.project=<BILLING_PROJECT>
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$$anonfun$instance$lzycompute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BigQuery.scala:156)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$$anonfun$instance$lzycompute$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BigQuery.scala:154)
[error]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$$anonfun$instance$lzycompute$2.apply(BigQuery.scala:154)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$$anonfun$instance$lzycompute$2.apply(BigQuery.scala:154)
[error]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$.instance$lzycompute(BigQuery.scala:154)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$.instance(BigQuery.scala:150)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.client.BigQuery$.defaultInstance(BigQuery.scala:176)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.TypeProvider$.bigquery$lzycompute(TypeProvider.scala:42)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.TypeProvider$.bigquery(TypeProvider.scala:42)
[error]         at com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.TypeProvider$.tableImpl(TypeProvider.scala:53)
[error]   @BigQueryType.fromTable("sandbox-data:Users.uid")
[error]    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

My `build.sbt` file is:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.{util, _}

val scioVersion = "0.7.4"
val beamVersion = "2.11.0"
val scalaMacrosVersion = "2.1.1"

//logLevel := util.Level.Debug

lazy val commonSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
  organization := "haaretz",
  // Semantic versioning http://semver.org/
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-target:jvm-1.8",
    "-deprecation",
    "-feature",
    "-unchecked"),
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
)

lazy val paradiseDependency =
  "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % scalaMacrosVersion cross CrossVersion.full
lazy val macroSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  addCompilerPlugin(paradiseDependency)
)

lazy val root: Project = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(macroSettings)
  .settings(
    name := "htz-dataflow",
    description := "DataFlow pipelines for htz projects",
    publish / skip := true,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.spotify" %% "scio-core" % scioVersion,
      "com.spotify" %% "scio-bigquery" % scioVersion,
      "com.spotify" %% "scio-test" % scioVersion % Test,
      "org.apache.beam" % "beam-runners-direct-java" % beamVersion,
      "org.apache.beam" % "beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java" % beamVersion,
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.25",
      "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.3",
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.8",
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.1",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.26",
    )
  )
  .enablePlugins(PackPlugin)

lazy val repl: Project = project
  .in(file(".repl"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(macroSettings)
  .settings(
    name := "repl",
    description := "Scio REPL for POC",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.spotify" %% "scio-repl" % scioVersion
    ),
    Compile / mainClass := Some("com.spotify.scio.repl.ScioShell"),
    publish / skip := true
  )
  .dependsOn(root)
```

If you need any additional info, comment and I'll provide It.

Comment: Does `sbt -Dbigquery.project=... {compile,pack}` work for you? Alternatively you can set a default project with `gcloud config set project [PROJECT]`

Comment: @NevilleLi yes, It worked. Thanks! You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `sbt -Dbigquery.project=... {compile,pack}`, i.e. the JVM flags should be before sbt tasks.
Alternatively you can set a default project with `gcloud config set project [PROJECT]`.